# The simulated $((1-\alpha )\times 100)^{th}$ percentiles of the null distribution of a specific statistic

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, quantiles

I've written this algorithm in R program:
[image]

as following

```
n=20
mu=100
sigma=10
N=10000
alpha=0.05     
D=array(0, dim=N)
for(j in 1:N){
    x=rnorm(n,mu,sigma)
    x=sort(x) 
    z=dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x))  # R can do it at once
    num = sum( abs(z - seq(1,n)/n ) ) 
    den = sum( pmax(z, seq(1,n)/n) )
    D[j]=num/den
}
sort(D)[N*alpha]
```

The output is $0.4690684$. But it must be about $0.1232$. Is there something wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, this is not a coding site.   As it happens, though, you have two readily-identifiable problems.   First, you are calculating the $\alpha$ percentile in your last line, not the $(1-\alpha)$ percentile.   Second, you are using `dnorm` instead of `pnorm` to calculate the $z_i$.

Comment: @jbowman You are right. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: Dear @panda , thank you very much for your answer. Could you please tell me how I can compute the power of the test below in R?

Comment: @jbowman I am very sorry to bother you again. I was wondering if you could tell me how I can compute the power of the proposed test in R?

Comment: This is a new question, so it's better that you ask it as one.

Comment: @jbowman I asked it as a new question here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/266095/247184. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jbowman is right.

```
delta <- vector()
for (i in 1:10000){
x <- rnorm(20, 100, 10)
x <- sort(x)
z <- pnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x))
delta[i] <- sum(abs(z-seq(1,20)/20))/sum(pmax(z, seq(1,20)/20))
}
plot(density(delta))
quantile(delta, 1-0.05)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It works properly.

Comment: I am very sorry to bother you again. I was wondering if you could tell me how I can compute the power of the proposed test in R Here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/540480/242174 .